# How to refence cell in a sas database

Tags: sas

I have a quick question. In excel you can refer to the value in row 20, column c as the C20 cell. What is the equivalent expression in a SAS database?

Answer (score 2):

It's not really useful to think of a SAS dataset like a spreadsheet. Rather, think about it like a database table. Extracting a particular row is easy, but extracting a column requires a name rather than a position, like C in Excel.

If this is the dataset

```
    x1   x2   x3
  +----+----+----
1 |  0 |  1 |  0
2 |  1 |  2 |  3
```

Then in a data step, you can get the equivalent of B2 like so:

```
data b2;
    set dataset;
    if _n_ = 2 then output;
    keep x2;
run;
```

The output dataset will then contain only the value you want. But you have to *know* that `x2`, for example, is the variable you want.

This isn't really what SAS is for, though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot explicitly refer to a single cell external to a dataset out of context, like you can in Excel.  SAS processes rows one at a time, and does not naturally have the ability to directly access a cell.

In general, if you're referring to the value in a discussion, you would refer to the column as a variable. You could refer to the row number, although that has very little meaning in most instances (particularly as you can sort a dataset, changing all of the row numbers); instead, you would refer to it by its primary key.  This would be whatever defines a unique row in your data.  It might be a subject ID, for example, or some combination of several variables that together define a unique row.

Comment: This is applicable to base SAS only, by the way; SAS/IML would have a different answer.